# pass object from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a convention object that i have to pass as an input to a child component, the convention id is displayed when i call it in the child's template, but i get undefined when i try to use my the convention in a console.log. 
I tried placing my console.log in the constructor of the child as well as in ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit and ngOnChanges. For ngOnChanges when i pass only the id of the convention as an input to the child component it works just fine, but i need to pass the convention not its id.

**index.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './index.template.html',
    selector: 'be-convention-update',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ConventionUpdateComponent {

    private convention$: Convention;
    private conventionId: number;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conventionService: ConventionService) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: any) => {
                this.conventionId = params['id'];
                this.conventionService.getOne(this.conventionId).subscribe(response => this.convention$ = response);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

**index.template.html**

```
<be-form-convention [convention]="convention$"></be-form-convention>
```

**form.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'be-form-convention',
    templateUrl: './form.template.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ConventionFormComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

    @Input() convention: Convention;

    constructor() {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.convention); //undefined
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.convention); //undefined
    }

    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      const object: SimpleChange = changes.convention;
      console.log('prev value: ', object.previousValue); //undefined
      console.log('got name: ', object.currentValue); //undefined
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you actually get your convention object from you conventionService.getOne ?

Comment: The `$` suffix screams observable and "in need of async pipe" but it's unclear to say the least what you are doing and why you are doing it.

Comment: @Orodan yes i get the convention object from my service

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are right but this is not related to my problem

Comment: From what I can see here, you're doing it right, can you show your ConventionUpdateComponent template and the Convention model please ?

Comment: @Orodan i'm modifying my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to do some operation, when you receive input or input value changes.

You can use input directive with set function, like below:

```
_convention: Convention;
@Input()
set convention(convention: Convention) {
    this._convention = convention;
    //the code you want to handle after input is received
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the same result. I have to mention that when i create a new object and send it to the child instead of calling my service, it works. so i guess that the problem is in the service it self

Comment: The issue in this case can be, the value is passed by reference. So the changes in object sometimes does not call any event in child component. But it gets value because the reference variable is same. So, you can text it by passing a fresh object reference, with same value. You can also try by passing object of type any in place of Convention, and pass input value as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectvariable)); this will create a fresh variable, so your child component should be responding to the changes.

Comment: what do you mean pass input value as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectvariable));

Comment: this will create a copy, of the variable, so the value passed will not be by reference. Just to try, if the problem is because of value passed by reference. If you know the problem, you can better handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an async operation I suggest you wait until the convention gets the value use `*ngIf` to load child-component when convention object is not empty

```
<ng-container *ngIf="convention$">
<be-form-convention [convention]="convention$"></be-form-convention>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Aymen Kanzari did u try this?

Comment: Yes when i tried it, the html of the child component (ConventionFormComponent) didn't appear

Comment: it means your object is always empty? what do u c when u do a console.log(this.convention$) inside subscribe

Comment: it's not empty, it displays data in the console when i do a console.log(this.convention$) inside subscribe

Comment: create a plunker or stackblitz

Answer (score -3):

For component-component communication i always use a service.

What i do is: i create a service and make two functions (getData and setData).

when ever i want to send some data from one component to another i call the setData method and when i want to receive the data in other component i use getData method.

Here is an example:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class DataExchange {

  data; //Global Variable of 'any' type.

  setData(data){
this.data = data;
  }

getData():any{
  return this.data;
}
}
```